# Problems with Serial Port Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb

I've been in troubles with a little ESP8266 chip wifi module. Last week I had  my Ubuntu 15 working with the chip in usb-serial connection, but when I connect I type:

```
    dmesg
```

and I can see that Ubuntu is giving the file /dev/ttyUSB0 , but in a moment it disconnect from tty0 . 
I don't know if is my usb-serial port, or I don't have the drivers, or something.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strange problem with a Microchip MCP2200 USB to RS232 adaptor under Ububtu 16.04.  Everything looks OK and it receives correctly but for some reason the chip it's supposed to be talking to ignores it.